# Sharepoint 2013 - Fetch only last approved version through REST api

Tags: api, rest, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

Before I ask my question I want to give you a quick overview about the topic.

I got a sharepoint list (SP 2013) which has content approval feature enabled. For this list you can choose who should see the draft versions of an item. Most logic option here is to let the author and all approvers see the draft. Now imagine that an item has been approved and now again edited. There is a version that is draft (because it needs to be approved again) and a version that had been approved before.

Here comes the tricky part :-). I fetch the items of that list via REST api. My query includes "_ModerationStatus eq 0" which means that I only fetch approved items. Users who are not allowed to see drafts automatically get the last-approved version of the item, although there is a draft version waiting to be approved. Users who are allowed to see draft versions see (I would expect something different here) NOTHING! So instead of fetching the last-approved item, the query has no result for users which are able to see drafts. Now if I perform the query without "_ModerationStatus eq 0" these users see the draft version while others (not allowed to see drafts) still see the last-approved version.

So finally my question is: Is there any chance to change this beaviour? I want SP to return the last approved version for ALL users via REST api. If these users open the SP-list itself they sure should see the draft. So it is only about the rest api.

I don´t think that this is possible (did not find anything to change this) and I thik the REST api just mirrors the behaviour of the native view behaviour of the SP-list-view itself.

Thank you in advance!
regards 
Ben

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are two possible solutions for this problem:

1. Create a second list and let a workflow create or update items on this list whenever a new or updated item has been approved on the main list.

A: Worklist -> New or changed Item -> Workflow -> Create or update item on List B: Productionlist

Use the unique ID of items to check if an item does already exist on list B.

2. You can read about the second possible solution here: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/116921/distinguish-between-approved-and-not-approved-items-rest-api

With OData__ModerationStatus it is possible to get the approval status for each item that your request fetched via REST. So you could probably place a flag DRAFT to any not approved draft versions to let the author and all approvers know that this is not an approved version.

Of course it is possible to get the last approved versions for each item but that will cause a need for additional requests and validation etc.

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score -1):

Just use the following,

```
http://WebAppUrl/_api/web/getfilebyserverrelativeurl('/RelativePathToFile')/MajorVersion
```

Example:

```
http://contoso.com/_api/web/getfilebyserverrelativeurl('/_catalogs/masterpage/css/main.css')/MajorVersion
```

That returns the recent major version published